# Knockout bind select with custom object with observable properties

Tags: javascript, select, knockout.js, data-binding, bind

I'm trying to bind a `<select>` with Knockout. In my ViewModel I have 2 different objects, each with observable properties.

First object is `Property` which has a `headquarter_id` as a `ko.observable()`.
Second object is `Headquarter` which has an `id` and a `name`, both as `ko.observable()`.

What I'm trying to do, is bind a select with an `ko.observableArray()` of `Headquarter` objects, like this:

```
<select id="headquarters" data-bind="options: HeadquarterOptions, optionsText: name, optionsValue: id, optionsCaption: '--Select--', value: Property().headquarter_id"></select>
```

But I keep getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "options: function (){return HeadquarterOptions }"
> Message: id is not defined

Here is how my ViewModel looks like:

```
var Property = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.headquarter_id = ko.observable();
}

var Headquarter = function (id, name) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
}

var headquarterOptions = [
        new Headquarter(1, "hq 1"),
        new Headquarter(2, "hq 2"),
        new Headquarter(3, "hq 3"),
    ]

var PropertiesViewModel = function (app, dataModel) {
    var self = this;
    self.Property = ko.observable(new Property());
    self.HeadquarterOptions = ko.observableArray(headquarterOptions);
}
    
ko.applyBindings(PropertiesViewModel);
```

How can I achieve this?
Here's my current fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juandozco/dzwnb05b/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go http://jsfiddle.net/dzwnb05b/4/

```
<select class="form-control" id="headquarter" data-bind="options: HeadquarterOptions, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: '--Select--', value: Property().headquarter_id"></select>
```

You were missing single quotation marks around name and id.

Comment: Off course! Thanks a lot, didnt notice. Lost a lot of time because of this.

Answer (score 2):

`optionsValue` and `optionsText` should be declared as functions instead of values (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html):

```
optionsText: function(item) {return item.name; }
optionsValue: function(item){ return item.id; }
```

Check out the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzwnb05b/3/

Comment: It works, but @Beyond Programming gave the correct answer. Thank you tho.